# TypeScript: Define type that can be bool or null

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that can return either true, false or null.

How do I define this type? For now, as a temporary solution, I define it as `boolean | string`, but it's misleading, someone may thing that it really may return string...  Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you tried the obvious `boolean | null`. How did it not work?

Comment: Of course I did. My WebStorm won't let me use it this way. Perhaps it's because of the TS version? I use 1.8, bundled to WS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on which typescript version you are using.

- before 2.0 `null` can be returned on ("is in the domain of") any type, so `boolean` is your type
- starting with 2.0, if you enable `--strictNullChecks` then you have to specify that a type can return `null`. So your type will be `boolean | null`

More details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/) paragraph `Non-nullable Types`

Comment: Can't you also use `function foo() : boolean?` to make the type nullable?

Answer (score 1):

By default, **null** and undefined are subtypes of all other types, so you just specify that the return value is boolean and you are good.

```
function foo(): boolean {

    return null; // OK
}
```

Comment: This is not correct in newer versions of TS if using the recommended compiler setting `--strictNullChecks`.

Comment: You are correct, so I changed my answer to "by default"

Comment: Nowadays words "by default" can be misleading, better would be use "historically" or "plain JS" or "TS version < 2.0".

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
let isItNullable: boolean | null = true;
isItNullable = null;
console.log(isItNullable);
```