# What is the use of defining null as a data type?

Tags: typescript, types, null

We're learning `TypeScript` and while declaring a variable we tried to specify its type too like this

```
let a: number = 5;
let b: boolean;
let c: string;
let d: any;

let e: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let f: any[] = [true, 'foo', 4.09, []];

let g: null;
```

These `any` and `null` were new to us, we were able to understand the concept of `any`, but it's confusing with `null`. This is the first time we are hearing about `null` as a `data type`, we've heard `null` as a value in `Java`. The really confusing thing is why someone would need a data type as `null`.

In Java, we declare variables as

```
int a = 0;
double b = 0.0;
char c = 'c';
String x = "abc";
```

But if `null` is a data type, it will like this

```
null a;
```

We're finding it difficult to understand this concept! If null is assigned to a variable its cool, **nothing is there** that's it, but what is the purpose of having null as a data type? So we looked at some websites

[Data types in TypeScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-typescript/) - here its says **It is used when an object does not have any value**, but does it mean assign null if an object doesn't have a value or specify null as a type to those objects which don't have any value?

Here in [How to declare a type as nullable in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220114/how-to-declare-a-type-as-nullable-in-typescript) and [TypeScript: Define type that can be bool or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533120/typescript-define-type-that-can-be-bool-or-null), the discussion was about assigning/returning null to some variable.

So can anybody help us with clearing this concept of null being used as a data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript and in TypeScript, `null` is a perfectly good *value*. You're right that it represents nothingness, more or less, but it is good to have a value that stands for the absence of something. Consider:

```
let supervisor = "None"    // I have a supervisor named "None"
let supervisor = null      // I DON'T HAVE a supervisor
let supervisor = undefined // Maybe I have a supervisor, maybe
                           // I don't, I don't know or care, or
                           // none of your business
```

Now you asked about `null` as a type. Great! It is easy to get confused between the value `null` and the type `null`. But here's how you can understand it. TypeScript has *unit types*, which are types that have only a single value. Did you know that `5` is a type? (It is the type whose only value is the number 5. Did you know that `"dog"` is a type? (The type whose only value is `"dog"`. Yep, you can say:

```
let x: "dog" = "dog";
let y: 5 = 5;
```

Now since `null` is a value, there exists a type called `null` also. It is the type whose only value is `null`. It's a unit type, just like the two above.

```
let z: null = null;
```

Now if your question was "why would I ever declare such a type in a real application?" that's a good question too. Perhaps you might not *explicitly* declare a type like that, but you very well might want a type like:

```
number | null
```

This could be the result type for a function that converts an string to a number. Note the union type `T1 | T2`, where T1 and T2 are types. If there was no such type as `null`, then `number | null` would not be the union of two types, and things would be weird. Things are so much more clean when you have unit types! And since `null` is a value, then there needs to be a type `null` containing just the value `null`.

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting its entirely a different view, `let x: "dog" = "do";` gave error and will only compile when written like `let x: "dog" = "dog";`. Cool and thanks, it says we got a long way to go :):)

Comment: For more information on unit types (and all the other types) I recommend [this section of Anders Hejlsberg's talk at Build 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDACN-BGvI8&feature=youtu.be&t=27m) I think it will help you a lot. Cheers.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran what is also good is having stuff like `function favorite(pet:"cat"|"dog") {}` so you could only enter `"cat"` or `"dog"` but could not enter `"fish"`.